# What error will I get when I try to pass an empty field in multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I want to check if the image field given to Multer will contain the file or not.

Multer does not throwing any error and server is just processing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change that in the endpoint handler.

```js
router.post('/upload-image', multer.single('file'), async (req, res) => {

  if(!req.file) {
    console.log('File is not uploaded');
  } 

});
```